# Is there a way to easily compress a section of the an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, scaling

I have [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMkDK.jpg) and although the data below 0% is important enough that it needs to be displaying, it's too infrequent to warrant skewing the entire graph. Is there a way to make it such that below 0% the scale is reduced/compressed so the same distance gives a larger change in %. (I don't want to use a broken axis because there may be other data <0%)

I have seen [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html) is possible way of doing it however all I want is a linear scale for < 0%, just with a different scaling value. Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: Changing your yaxis to `log` scale is the only way I can think of!

Comment: @ThePredator can't have a logscale for negative y values...

Comment: If anything it makes the problem worse as the section with most of the data in is compressed to the top quarter of the graph (and subtleties in the data are less clear) Edit: and what @tom said

Comment: @tom Yeah!! Forgot!!

Comment: Would it be possible to embed your image `this graph` in your OP and also to add a minimal example of the code you are currently using to plot your graph.

Comment: I just figured it out, it's a bit of a fudge but I'll post how I did it later. (@Jean-Sébastien it wouldn't allow me because this is my first post, thanks anyway)

Comment: But you could scale your axes so the negative values are positive and apply a log

Comment: Ah ok I see. Please do post your answer later, I'm interested to see how you've done it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option would be indeed to create a custom projection for your axes. In theory it shouldn't be too difficult since you want a linear scale with just a different scale for positive and negative values, but you'll still have to to write quite a bit of code to create the relevant class.

http://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html
and as you already linked: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work around but it's a bit of a fudge. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBPeV.png)

Here's the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.set_window_title("Frame-to-frame pump-to-probe")
plt.xlabel(r'$t/ps$')
plt.ylabel(r'%')
min = 0
for i in range(len(ftf_PtmPlist)):
    if ftf_PtmPlist[i] < min:
        min = ftf_PtmPlist[i]
    if ftf_PtmPlist[i] < 0:
        ftf_PtmPlist[i] = 2*ftf_PtmPlist[i]/10.0
for i in range(len(ftf_PttPlist)):
    if ftf_PttPlist[i] < min:
        min = ftf_PttPlist[i]
    if ftf_PttPlist[i] < 0:
        ftf_PttPlist[i] = 2*ftf_PttPlist[i]/10.0
lables = [0,20,40,60,80,100]
ymin = int(20*math.floor(min/100.0))
for y in range(ymin,-19,20):
    lables.append(y)
lables = sorted(lables)
for i in range(-ymin/20):
    lables[i] = str(int(lables[i]*10/2.0))
ax.set_yticklabels(lables)
plt.plot(timelist,ftf_PtmPlist,'magenta', label='pump to main probe efficiency')
plt.plot(timelist,ftf_PttPlist,'teal', label='pump to total probe efficiency')
plt.plot(timelist,p_deplist,'orange', label='pump energy depletion')
plt.gca().set_ylim(top=105)
plt.gca().set_xlim(left=-1.0)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.55, 0.17), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., prop={'size':10})
```

First I scale all values less than 0 by a factor of 0.2 for the two list which have the possibility for negative values while simultaneously looking for the most negative value overall. I then use this value to find what the most negative tick label should be (given the scaling I'm using) and create a list of new tick labels so the negative values display as the values they had before I scaled them down.

I know it's a bit sloppy but it does the job!